# Anime Series with Peter Pan and Flying Islands, Ships

Tags: story-identification, anime, peter-pan

I have been trying for years to find this anime series. I watched this series on TV, maybe in the 90's. I just remember that it was in the Neverland, there were flying islands and flying ships, Captain Hook had a flying pirate ship, and I remember that the crocodile was mechanical.

I would really appreciate it if you told me what series it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I searched Google for "peter pan anime", and found [*The Adventures of Peter Pan*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Peter_Pan), an anime series from **1989** - close enough to the '90s.

Episode 30, entitled "The Levitation Begins! **Hook's Flying Pirate Ship**" (emphasis mine), has this summary on Wikipedia:

> The boat seems to have driven off in the middle of the night. Peter and his band are stuck now on an island. The can't escape, because a huge fire-spitting monster fish burns everything that crosses the sea between the island and the shore. When it seems they're able to escape, a very powerful, flying new pirate ship appears, with Captain Hook on the deck ordering his pirates to load the cannon.

I couldn't find any reference to the crocodile itself being mechanical, but of course it makes a ticking noise due to the alarm clock - could that be what you were thinking of?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJ76Zor7nPY

Comment: Thank you very much I had found it before, but I thought it was another series because of the different intro, this is the intro I was used to:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXMFjK9Tx3k
I was confused with [*Fox's Peter Pan & the Pirates*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Pan_%26_the_Pirates) serie too, thanks again.
Greteengs